# How To Develop a Silverlight Shared Library (.dll) on a Mac?

Tags: silverlight, macos

does anyone have any suggestions for what I can do to try and create a SL Shared Library as a DLL file on a Mac? I've tried Eclipse with eclipse4sl and MonoDevelop, but I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. I had a nice streamlined process for this on a PC using VWD 2008. Basically what I want is this:

1.) A project that is strictly the code that will be compiled into the DLL shared library

2.) A separate project that links the uncompiled library code into a sample implementation so that I can tweak the library without going back and forth between projects and rebuilding the library all the time.

3.) (optional) another version of the sample implementation that uses the actual compiled library for final testing.

I'm managed to get a Silverlight app running using Eclipse, but I can't figure out if/how my shared library building is possible.

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Dude, define the problem. Your question has little detail and is open ended.  Until you define it better, we can't help you.

Comment: i don't know if there's any more detail I can give. I want to  build a Silverlight class library on a Mac, and I want the end result to be a shared DLL and not a packaged Silverlight XAP. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to target Moonlight, the Mono-based open source version of Silverlight.  Moonlight 2.0 was recently released, and with the proper support, MonoDevelop can be used to build Moonlight assemblies.

Here is a video that details how to set up and use MonoDevelop on the Mac to develop Moonlight code:

http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2009/05/07/moonlight_development_mac_using_monodevelop

Comment: I saw this, and attempted it, but I can't figure out what to do to get this out of a MonoDevelop into a DLL. It's important that it comes out as a DLL because it will be shared with MSVS developers.

Comment: Accepted answer, this is the only thing that successfully got me a DLL. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer would be to use a VM, running Windows with your dev tools inside it on your Mac.

Not sure on the *native-to-Mac-OS* route would be, however.

Comment: Good suggestion. I don't know if it's an option for me since it's a company-owned Mac I'm working on, but it could work. Thanks.